# for() está mostrando o mesmo valor do array

Tags: php, mysql, array, echo

Boa tarde,
Estou tentando fazer um for() que mostre os valores referentes à categoria atual. Utilizo uma função que pega a empresa e a categoria e seleciona a quantidade de registros para mostrar. Logo depois utilizo uma função bem semelhante para mostrar os produtos dentro do for. porém ele esta me mostrando várias vezes o mesmo produto.

Seguem as Funções:

```
function selectProdutos($idCategoria, $idEmpresa){
    require('admin/Connections/pennaConect.php');

    mysql_select_db($database_pennaConect, $pennaConect);
    $query_ListaProdutos = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_produto 
                                    WHERE tbl_categoria_id = %s 
                                    AND tbl_empresa_id = %s 
                                    ORDER BY codigo_original", 
                                        GetSQLValueString($idCategoria, "int"),
                                        GetSQLValueString($idEmpresa, "int")
                                );
    $ListaProdutos = mysql_query($query_ListaProdutos, $pennaConect) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_ListaProdutos = mysql_fetch_assoc($ListaProdutos);
    $totalRows_ListaProdutos = mysql_num_rows($ListaProdutos);

    return $row_ListaProdutos;
}

function selectCountProdutos($idCategoria, $idEmpresa){
    require('admin/Connections/pennaConect.php');

    mysql_select_db($database_pennaConect, $pennaConect);
    $query_ListaProdutos = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_produto 
                                    WHERE tbl_categoria_id = %s 
                                    AND tbl_empresa_id = %s 
                                    ORDER BY codigo_original", 
                                        GetSQLValueString($idCategoria, "int"),
                                        GetSQLValueString($idEmpresa, "int")
                                );
    $ListaProdutos = mysql_query($query_ListaProdutos, $pennaConect) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_ListaProdutos = mysql_fetch_assoc($ListaProdutos);
    $totalRows_ListaProdutos = mysql_num_rows($ListaProdutos);

    return $totalRows_ListaProdutos;
}
```

e no HTML:

```
            <?php for($i=0;$i<selectCountProdutos($row_ListaCategoria['CatId'] , $row_listaFabrica['id']);$i++){ ?>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3-edit thumb">
                    <div class="box clearfix">

                        <!--IMAGEM PRODUTO-->
                        <a href="img/produtos/id/101.1032.png" class="thumbnail text-center thumbnail-edit thumbnail_wrapper no-border-radius pop" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="CHICOTE PARA REPARO ALTERNADOR VW/CHICOTE P/REPARO SENSOR PRESS" data-footer="TC Chicotes">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-form-edit" src="img/produtos/id/101.1032.png" alt="#" />
                        </a>

                        <!--INFORMAÇÕES PRODUTO-->
                        <div class="product-text">
                        <?php $result = selectProdutos($row_ListaCategoria['CatId'], $row_listaFabrica['id']);?>
                            <h4><?php echo $result['nome']; ?></h4>
                            <p>
                                <strong>Código:</strong> <?php echo $result['codigo_original']; ?><br>
                                <strong>Aplicação:</strong> <?php echo $result['aplicacao']; ?><br>
                                <strong>Obs:</strong><?php echo $result['descricao']; ?>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Podem me ajudar? Não estou entendendo o que está errado e muito menos como concertar.

Agradeço a todos que dispuserem ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu método `selectProdutos` retorna apenas o primeiro produto. O `mysql_fetch_assoc` retorna um valor a cada vez que o usa, então você deve guardar todos os dados em vetores.

```
/*...*/
while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($ListaProdutos))
    $row_ListaProdutos[] = $line;
/*...*/
return $row_ListaProdutos;
```

Então todas as informações irão retornar dentro do seu vetor.

E no seu html:

```
<?php
$result = selectProdutos($row_ListaCategoria['CatId'], $row_listaFabrica['id']);
for($i=0;$i<selectCountProdutos($row_ListaCategoria['CatId'] , $row_listaFabrica['id']);$i++){ ?>
...
<div class="product-text">
    <h4><?php echo $result[$i]['nome']; ?></h4>
    ...
</div>
...
```

> `...` representa o trecho do código até a próxima ***tag***

Comment: Eu realmente não estava entendendo isso. Na minha ideia mysql_fetch_assoc estava me retornando array. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score -1):

Cara bati o olho rápido, na linha do "`for`",  acho que teria que ficar assim:

```
<?php $result = selectProdutos($row_ListaCategoria[$i], $row_listaFabrica[$i]);?>
```

Como você esta montando esse `$row_ListaCategoria` e `$row_listaFabrica`?
Se for por `mysql_fetch_assoc`, tente mudar para `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: Olá! tudo tranquilo, consegui resolver com ajuda do colega acima. o erro era que não estava retornando um array. Sua solução poderia ajudar também, depois vou tentar. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!